# pivot display for multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

I have this code

```
SELECT
    StockItem.ItemTitle,
    StockItem.ItemNumber,
    ProductCategories.CategoryName,
    StockItem.ItemDescription,
    PurchaseItem.Quantity AS QuantityOrdered,
    Purchase.DateOfPurchase,
    Purchase.DateOfDelivery,
    Purchase.ExternalInvoiceNumber as PONumber,
    Purchase.QuotedDeliveryDate,
    StockLevel.Quantity AS CurrentQuantity,
    StockLevel.OnOrder,
    StockLevel.MinimumLevel
FROM dbo.PurchaseItem
INNER JOIN dbo.Purchase
    ON PurchaseItem.fkPurchasId = Purchase.pkPurchaseID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.StockItem
    ON PurchaseItem.fkStockItemId = StockItem.pkStockItemID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.StockLevel
    ON StockLevel.fkStockItemId = StockItem.pkStockItemID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ProductCategories
    ON ProductCategories.CategoryId = StockItem.CategoryId
where ProductCategories.CategoryName = 'default'
```

that will return the value

```
ItemTitle   ItemNumber  CategoryName    ItemDescription QuantityOrdered DateOfPurchase  DateOfDelivery  PONumber    QuotedDeliveryDate  CurrentQuantity OnOrder MinimumLevel
FBIM01      FBIM01      Default         Default         10              5/19/2011 0:00  7/6/2011 15:19  POA90949    6/24/2011 0:00      20              160     50
FBIM01      FBIM01      Default         Default         20              5/27/2011 0:00  6/23/2011 0:00  POA90950    6/24/2011 0:00      20              160     50
FBIM01      FBIM01      Default         Default         30              6/20/2011 0:00  6/23/2011 0:00  POA90951    6/24/2011 0:00      20              160     50
FBIM01      FBIM01      Default         Default         100             6/15/2011 0:00  6/23/2011 0:00  POA90952    6/24/2011 0:00      20              160     50
```

However,i have been scratching my head trying to get it to display as

```
ItemTitle   ItemNumber  CategoryName    ItemDescription QuantityOrdered QuantityOrdered2    QuantityOrdered3    QuantityOrdered4    PONumber1   PONumber2   PONumber3   PONumber4   CurrentQuantity OnOrder MinimumLevel            
FBIM01      FBIM01      Default         Default         10              20                  30                  100                 POA90949    POA90950    POA90951    POA90952    20              160     50
```

My skill is just not there. Would you gurus please help me solving this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTE AS
(
    SELECT
    StockItem.ItemTitle,
    StockItem.ItemNumber,
    ProductCategories.CategoryName,
    StockItem.ItemDescription,
    PurchaseItem.Quantity AS QuantityOrdered,
    Purchase.DateOfPurchase,
    Purchase.DateOfDelivery,
    Purchase.ExternalInvoiceNumber as PONumber,
    Purchase.QuotedDeliveryDate,
    StockLevel.Quantity AS CurrentQuantity,
    StockLevel.OnOrder,
    StockLevel.MinimumLevel,
    ROW_NUMBER()Over(Partition by StockItem.ItemTitle Order by StockItem.ItemTitle) As Rn
    FROM dbo.PurchaseItem
    INNER JOIN dbo.Purchase ON PurchaseItem.fkPurchasId = Purchase.pkPurchaseID
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.StockItem ON PurchaseItem.fkStockItemId = StockItem.pkStockItemID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.StockLevel ON StockLevel.fkStockItemId = StockItem.pkStockItemID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ProductCategories ON ProductCategories.CategoryId = StockItem.CategoryId
    where ProductCategories.CategoryName = 'default'
)
Select ItemTitle,ItemNumber,
    CategoryName,
    ItemDescription,
    Quantity AS QuantityOrdered,
    DateOfPurchase,
    DateOfDelivery,
    ExternalInvoiceNumber as PONumber,
    QuotedDeliveryDate,
    Quantity AS CurrentQuantity,
    OnOrder,
    MinimumLevel,
From CTE
where rn=1
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me Yogesh. Unfortunately, the given code didn't work as it only output the very first PO number and quantity ordered. It skipped the last 3.

Comment: Hi John, I got wrong. this is specific to pivot query. You will need to get data using the pivot as I am not clear with your current description so if possible than provide clear explanation what you needed?

Comment: i am not sure how to explain it clearer than i already have. Would you please tell me what information should i include here?
Thank you

Comment: provide me table script with some data than I will definitely provide you the working sql query.

Comment: i do have the table schema but i don't have access to the data. What happened is that i am using a service provider that take care of our statistical collection. Occasionally, we need to get some data from their remote server. They do provide some pre written scripts that extract different data. However, none of them met my requirements. Therefore i have to write the custom script which their software also can execute. So if the table schema can be of used, how can i attach it here?
Thanks

Comment: must visit this [link](http://sqlwithmanoj.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/dynamic-pivot/)